# Missing class datepicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am developing an android application using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 and I need datepicker on my input form. However, when I insert it, IDEA gives "Missing class DatePicker" warning in the preview window and I launch application on the phone it crashes. If I remove datepicker element, application works properly.

I am using android 2.2 as a target platform and java 1.6 as java SDK.

Here's source code of my form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/l_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:text="Some text: "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fnt_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/source"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Some text: "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fnt_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/destination"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Some text: "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fnt_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:endYear="2011"
    android:startYear="2011"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fnt_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i dont have idea, but Eclipse is best for android development. Is there a special need to use Intelli J ?

Comment: No special need, but I find this IDE most convenient :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I have [filed bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35151) for this issue (Android <= 2.3).

So I was able to reproduce case that you have. Indeed *IDEA* signals that's there's some issue and app is crashing. Using Eclipse will not help (checked it) - *Graphical Layout* view in there will also signals that it cannot create `DatePicker` object.

#### ROOT CAUSE

It occurs that the problem in your case is that `android:startYear` and `android:endYear` do not include current year on the device (range 2011-2011 does not include 2012 - current year).

This is probably a bug in `DatePicker` implementation (prior to API 11) which [tries to init the widget with current date](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/DatePicker.java/#167) regardless whether or not `android:startYear` and `android:endYear` define range that have current year within it.

#### SOLUTION

Because you are using API level 9, there are no `android:minDate` or `android:maxDate` properties (introduced in API 11). So to restrict date picking to any range of years (workaround for the above mentioned bug), you can implement your own `OnDateChangedListener`.

Example code with comments:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date);

        final int MIN_YEAR = 2011;
        final int MAX_YEAR = 2011;

        datePicker.init(MIN_YEAR /* initial year */,
                        01 /* initial month of year */,
                        01 /* initial day of month */,
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker,
                                              int year,
                                              int monthOfYear,
                                              int dayOfMonth) {

                        // Override changing year to anything different from outside the range <MIN_YEAR, MAX_YEAR>
                        if (year < MIN_YEAR) {
                            datePicker.updateDate(MIN_YEAR, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        } else if (year > MAX_YEAR) {
                            datePicker.updateDate(MAX_YEAR, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear and concise answer with programmatic solution too. Definitely a vote-up.